Find equation of plane using a system of equations
I need to find the equation of a plane $\alpha$ which is parallel to the line:$$
l: \begin{cases}
x = -2 + t\\
y = 3 + t\\
z = 4 - t
\end{cases}
$$
and the line $g$ lies on the plane:$$
g: \begin{cases}
x = -2 + 2v\\
y = v\\
z = 2 - v
\end{cases}
$$
I found it to be: $\alpha: y+z-7=0$ using vector $g(2,1,-1) \parallel g$, vector $l(1,1,-1) \parallel l$ and vector $QS(x+2, y-3, z-4)$ (from point $Q(-2,3,4)$ (for $t=0$) on $l$ and random point that lies on the plane $S(x,y,z)$) and solving the determinant:
$$|QS,l,g|=0$$
My question is if there is another way to solve it, using a system of equations or something else?

Isn't $g$ a line, not a plane? I only see one free variable.

@TheoBendit $g$ is a line, as the OP wrote. They are searching a plane containing $g$ and parallel to $l$.

The solution is $$y+z-\color{red}2=0,$$
not $y+z-7=0.$
Your point $Q\in l$ is not supposed to lie on the plane, which contains $g$ but is only parallel to $l$. You should take some point of $g$ instead, like $(-2,0,2)$.
Apart from this mistake, your method was fine. Another one is to set and solve the system of equations on $a,b,c,d$ for the plane
$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ to satisfy the conditions.
$$\begin{cases}a+b-c=0\\
\forall v,\quad a(-2+2v)+bv+c(2-v)+d=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}c=a+b\\
\forall v,\quad(-2a+2c+d)+(2a+b-c)v=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}c=a+b\\
-2a+2c+d=0\\
2a+b-c=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff\begin{cases}c=a+b\\
d=-2b\\
-3a=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\iff(a,b,c,d)=b(0,1,1,-2),$$
and $b\ne0$ can be chosen arbitrarily, for instance $b=1$.

Yes, this was what I was looking for! Thanks! My only question is how do you go from line 1 to line 2 in the system of equations, can you elaborate more?

I inserted an intermediate step. I tacitly used moreover that a map $v\mapsto\alpha v+\beta$ is the zero map (if and) only if $\alpha=\beta=0$. This can be seen by substituting two distinct values for $v$: for instance, $v=0$ and $v=1$ gives $\beta=0$ and $\alpha+\beta=0$.


In $\mathbb R^3, A=(-2,3,4), u=(1,1,-1), l=A+\mathbb R u$
$B=(-2,0,2), v=(2,1,-1), g=B+\mathbb R v$
$\boxed{\color{blue}{\alpha : y+z=2}}$
The machine( geogebra ) uses another method : https://www.geogebra.org/classic/pry5qhp2
$u\times v=(0,-1,-1)$.
So, $\alpha= B+(u\times v)^\bot$ $$=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3: (x+2,y,z-2).(0,-1,-1)=0\}$$
